# ASP.NET MVC Type is not resolved for member MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I added a new property to my model of an ASP.NET MVC 5.2 application with MySQL database, and now I'd like to add a database migration for this by using this command:

```
Add-Migration RegisterPropertyAdded
```

But, I get an exception:

> Type is not resolved for member
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d

It seems that MySQL wants to throw an exception but can't find the exception class for reasons I don't understand. I installed the following NuGet packages in the project:

EntityFramework Version 6.1.3

MySql.Data Version 6.9.7

MySql.Data.Entities, Version 6.8.3.0

MySql.Data.Entity Version 6.9.7

In the model, the class `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException` is shown, so it seems like the class exists and I can't find any information that additional packages are required for the exception class.

Comment: Please show the class and property that you have added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to see this exception you have to update [MySQL Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
Also make sure that MySQL server is up and running and you can connect to it.

Comment: I was confused that this solves the problem because a few days ago it worked, although I hadn't install the MySQL Connector yet. So I thought It would have something to do with the package-updates I did via NuGet a few days before. But now I installed the MySQL Connector and it worked - strange issue! Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Ran into this when using MariaDB - the MariaDB installer doesn't install the Connector by default so you need to get it separately.

Answer (score 1):

For me this message appeared due to an **incorrect connection string in Web.config**.

Comment: I added MultipleActiveResultSets=true to my connection string and got this error with BetterModules.Core